# JPA: How to count child records without loading a lazy loaded set

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm writing a J2EE/JPA/Spring 3 application, trying to stay pure JPA 2.0. I want to get a count of child objects without having to load them, as it's obviously an expensive operation. For example here's a simplified example

```
Organisation
 - OrgID
 - OrgName

Employee
 - EmployeeID
 - OrgID (key to Organisation table)
 - EmployeeName
```

On a jsp page I want to show the list of all organisations and a count of the number of employees without loading the employees themselves. If it can be a single database hit that loads all the Organisation objects and somehow loads a count of the Employee objects that would be great. I'd rather avoid  one query to list the organisations then one for each organisation to count the employees. I guess I could add a transient property to hold the count, I'm not sure how to best do that.

Just to give an idea of scale, there will be around 50 organisations, and each organisation will have between 0 and 500 employees. I would rather avoid any implementation specific extensions, as I've changed JPA providers once and may change again.

In SQL I'd just do a join, group, and count, but I don't have a clue how to do it in JPA. Any help appreciated!

Comment: With JPA you can do a join, group, and a count. Study some good tutorial, then try and eventually come back if you have a specific problem

Comment: If you could point me at a resource that would be most useful. I've learned JPA by googling, and nothing simple comes up for that query - I've tried. I'm sure it's not that difficult, I just need a starting point. It's partly that if I did the query I don't know where to store the count and how to get it to the jsp.

Comment: I suggest to start with [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html) for JPQL, and [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/) for Criteria Queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select directly into an object that you define to be the result that holds the organisation and the count.  Then you just write the query.  The only trick is that you have to manually group by every field on the Organisation.  'GROUP BY ORGANISATION' is not legal.

```
public class OrgWithEmpCount {
  private Organisation org;
  private Long empCount;
  public OrgWithEmpCount(Organisation org, Long empCount) {
    this.org = org;
    this.empCount = empCount;
  }
}


Select new full.package.OrgWithEmpCount(o, count(e.employeeId)) 
from Organisation o, IN(o.employees) e 
group by o.orgId, o.orgName, o.whateverElse
```

Comment: That would mean you need a dto made for a page, which seems inelegant to me. I'll look into it tomorrow and give it a try, thank you.

Comment: You aren't *required* to make the object, you could just select the results and hibernate will give you back a `List<Object[]>` that you then separate yourself into the organisations and counts.  Guess it's personal preference which one is nicer :)

Comment: I'm not necessarily using hibernate, as I said pure JPA. I'll try it out later today when I have time though, thanks.

Comment: That worked great :) The only thing left to do is make the database query more efficient. Say the Organisation links to a ParentCompany entity via a ParentCompanyID, right now they're eagerly loaded but it's one database query per Organisation. The following query gives an error "query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list". Query is "Select new Organisation (o, count(e.employeeId)) from Organisation o, IN(o.employees) e JOIN FETCH o.parentCompany p WHERE o.organisationId group by o". Not even sure this is possible.

Comment: This looks good - but what about doing it similar to a LEFT JOIN? If an organization had no employees, I still want that organization listed and with a zero count.

Answer (score 2):

Going off of the the accepted answer from Affe - this worked except for the case of you wanting to have the count for companies even with no employees. The IN query will end up just excluding those companies. Hard to imagine a company with zero employees, but for the sake of the Query example, you could do it like this:

```
select new full.package.OrgWithEmpCount(o, count(e.employeeId))
FROM Organisation o LEFT JOIN e.employees AS e
group by o.orgId, o.orgName, o.whateverElse
```

You get the idea... just instead of doing an IN, do a LEFT JOIN.