# JPA: Constructor Expression causing 1+N Selects

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Following the advice listed here: [JPA: How to count child records without loading a lazy loaded set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682366/jpa-how-to-count-child-records-without-loading-a-lazy-loaded-set) implemented the below query:

```
SELECT new x.y.z.TreeInfo(t, count(l.id))
FROM Tree t LEFT JOIN t.branches b LEFT JOIN b.leaves l
GROUP BY t.id
```

The objective is to get the entire tree object and the number of leaves out of the database in **one** query.  Right now it gets the counts and the tree ids in the first query, and then it issues an additional query to load each tree.  Is there any way to tell it to fetch the entire tree object in the first query?  Is JPA the wrong tool for the job?

The equivalent SQL of what I want to do is this:

```
select *, (select count(*) 
          from leaf l join branch b on l.parentid = b.id
          where b.parentid = t.id)
from tree t
```

Comment: try to make same query without constructor query.

Answer (score 0):

It is really difficult to see what the problem is here, until you show more of the code and mapping. The problem could be, for example that by fetching the Tree (`select new TreeInfo (t, ... ) from Tree t...`) you end up loading the whole tree by eagerly fetching the object graph.

In general, though, fetching a tree from a database requires multiple queries because you don't know upfront how many nodes the longest branch contains and thus how many times you need to query for child nodes. JPA is not the problem here.

There are multiple strategies to solve this problem:

1. You can model the Tree as a separate entity (you seem to have done this) and have a foreign key to the tree in every node in the tree (not just the root nodes). Now you can fetch all nodes of a tree in one go, and have hibernate construct the tree structure by loading the parent nodes and hitting the session cache.
2. You can store the path to each node redundantly in each node (as a string of  IDs). This makes it easy to fetch a sub tree. It is difficult for updation when a structural change occurs, but this is often not required. Now you can select all nodes in a tree by selecting all nodes that have a path that starts with the ID of the root node. You would have to either flag leaf nodes and filter on the flag for counting or do the counting in memory.

You see that the only way to do what you want is to add redundant data to the nodes.

---

Either way, to count the number of leaves in a tree in SQL, you could do :

`select count(*) from node n left outer join node c on c.parent_id = n.id where c.id is null`

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  To clarify, I don't actually need or want the nodes, just the count.  There are several thousand leaves per tree, so it would be wasteful to load them.  The query in my question is executing as "select tree_id, (count leaves sub query) from tree".  It then goes back and selects each tree by id.  What I can't figure out how to do is make it select all the attributes of the tree object like it does if I just say "select from Tree".